# could not find function "objFun" in R?

Tags: r

I implemented the following code in R to simulate this algorithm :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#RMSProp

```
    RMSprop<-function(iter = 50000, alpha = 0.00001 ,lambda=0.1){

  # define the objective function f(x) 
  #objFun = function (x,y) return(20+(x^2-10*cos(2*pi*x))+(y^2-10*cos(2*pi*y)))
  #objFun = function (x,y) return(x^2+y^2)

  objFun = function (x,y) return((x^2+y-11)^2+(x+y^2-7)^2)

  #objFun = function (x,y) return(-20*exp(-0.2*sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2))) -exp(0.5*(cos(2*pi*x)+cos(2*pi*y)))+20+exp(1))
  # define the gradient of f(x) 

  # Note we don't split up the gradient

  # stoc_grad(iter = 1000, alpha = 0.01 )


  gradient_1 <- function(x , y) {
    #result<-c(2*x,0)
    #result<-c(2*x+20*pi*sin(2*pi*x), 0)
    result<-c(4*x^3+4*x*y-42*x+2*y^2-14 , 0)
    #result <- c(4*x*exp(-0.2*sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2)))/sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2))+pi*(sin(2*pi*x)+sin(2*pi*y))*exp(0.5*(cos(2*pi*x)+cos(2*pi*y))),0)

    return(result)
  }

  gradient_2 <- function(x , y) {
    #result<-c(0,2*y)
    #result<-c(0, 2*y+20*pi*sin(2*pi*y))
    result<-c(0,2*x^2+4*y^3+2*y+4*x*y-29)
    #result <- c(0, 4*y*exp(-0.2*sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2)))/sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2))+pi*(sin(2*pi*x)+sin(2*pi*y))*exp(0.5*(cos(2*pi*x)+cos(2*pi*y))))

    return(result)
  }

  gradient_3 <- function(x , y) {
    #result<-c(2*x,2*y)
    #result<-c(2*x+20*pi*sin(2*pi*x), 2*y+20*pi*sin(2*pi*y))
    result<-c(4*x^3+4*x*y-42*x+2*y^2-14,2*x^2+4*y^3+2*y+4*x*y-29)
    #result <- c(4*x*exp(-0.2*sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2)))/sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2))+pi*(sin(2*pi*x)+sin(2*pi*y))*exp(0.5*(cos(2*pi*x)+cos(2*pi*y))), 4*y*exp(-0.2*sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2)))/sqrt(0.5*(x^2+y^2))+pi*(sin(2*pi*x)+sin(2*pi*y))*exp(0.5*(cos(2*pi*x)+cos(2*pi*y))))

    return(result)
  }

  init = c(4,4)


  x <- init[1]
  y <- init[2]
  # create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
  x.All = numeric(iter)
  y.All = numeric(iter)
  tmp<-c(0,0)

V=(1-lambda)*(gradient_3(x,y))^2

  # gradient descent method to find the minimum
  for(i in seq_len(iter)){

    r = runif(1)
    if(r < 1/3){
      V=lambda*V + (1-lambda)*(gradient_1(x,y))^2
      tmp = c(x,y) - alpha*gradient_1(x,y)/sqrt(v)}
    else if(r < 2/3){
      V=lambda*V + (1-lambda)*(gradient_2(x,y))^2
      tmp = c(x,y) - alpha*gradient_2(x,y)/sqrt(v)}
    else{
      V=lambda*V + (1-lambda)*(gradient_3(x,y))^2
      tmp = c(x,y) - alpha*gradient_3(x,y)/sqrt(v)}}


    if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp[1], tmp[2]))) ) {
      x <- tmp[1]
      y <- tmp[2]
    }
    x.All[i] = x
    y.All[i] = y

    if (iter <=2000){
    print(c(i,x,y,objFun(x,y)))}

  }

  # print result and plot all xs for every iteration
  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x,y), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))
  plot(x.All, type = "l")  

  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x ,y), " at position y = ", y, sep = ""))
  plot(y.All, type = "l")  

}

RMSprop(iter = 1000, alpha = 0.01,lambda=0.9 )
```

It gives me the error : could not find function "objFun".
I know that this function exists !!!

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Solved !

The problem is in the variable V ( upper // lower case ).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/225478)

Comment: Ferdi : I'm the author of the post.